# Does an update on the Kafka Log Retention default value requires any downtime?

Tags: apache-kafka

Is any downtime/restart required for updating the log retention default configuration in Kafka

**Property Name** - log.retention.hours in Server.Properties

I performed runtime updates for a given topic, but couldn't find a perfect answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation on [Updating Broker Configs](https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation.html#brokerconfigs) you need to restart your broker before this configuration comes into effect:

> From Kafka version 1.1 onwards, some of the broker configs can be updated without restarting the broker. See the Dynamic Update Mode column in Broker Configs for the update mode of each broker config.

- **read-only**: Requires a broker restart for update
- **per-broker**: May be updated dynamically for each broker
- **cluster-wide**: May be updated dynamically as a cluster-wide default. May also be updated as a per-broker value for testing.

The description of the configuration `log.retention.hours` is shown below:

[image]

which means an update requires a broker restart.